# How can I use link_to to create a "blank" link in Rails 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I just want to create a link that does nothing when it is clicked (other than the jQuery code I am binding to the link's ID.

I am returning "false" in my Javascript function that is bound to the links, but I would just like the link to be "#" or something like that. When I try this:

```
link_to("Link", "#here")
```

That gives me the entire current url, plus "#here" stuck on the end.

Comment: This might not be the answer you want, but you should use a `<button>` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<%= "Link", "javascript:void(0)" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<%= link_to "TEXT" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `<%= link_to('#', :id => 'link_id', :class => 'some_class') %>`

**Edit**

Sorry, I just now saw that this question pertains to Rails 2.3.11. I looked at the api and it looks like it may still work, but if it doesn't, let me know and I'll remove this answer.